# Check how many times value of column change when other column value is specific

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have one dataframe with two columns A, and B . I want to check if column A value is greater than 5 continues, for this continuous time how many times value of column B value increase and how many times vaue decrease.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,3,8,6,7,11,1,15,20,15,16,87],
                 'B':[1,3,4,6,11,6,11,7,11,15,6,87,16]})
 df_out = pd.DataFrame({'values increase count':[5],
                     'values decrease count':[3]})
```

Comment: Can you add the expected output to the question? Can you rephrase this line `column B value is greater than 5 continues for this continuous time how many times value of column A goes up and how many times go down.`?

Comment: Your two arrays for `A` and `B` are not of the same size.